# Exiting from the middle of a drools rule

Tags: return, drools, business-rules

In java method we can return from the middle skipping the rest of the method code being executed. e.g.

```
public String doSomething(){

    step 1
    step 2

    if(some condition){
        return "Exited from the middle";
    }

    step 4

    return "Whole code is executed"
}
```

Is there a way to do such things in a drools rule?

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple:

```
return;
```

Since there's no place of invocation for a single rule you can control, or write code doing that, a return with an expression is not vailable. You can collect values you'd like to return in a global variable, `List<String>` or, perhaps, `Map<String,List<String>>` with rule names acting as keys.

**Clarification**
A rule's right hand side results in a static method with `void` as result type. A return statement just acts naturally.

Comment: Does 'return' exit only that rule or exit from the entire .drl file as .drl file has many rules whether it skip rest of the rules?

Comment: It just terminates the execution of a Drools rule's right hand side. For exiting a fire command, use the session's `halt()` method.

Comment: does it mean it skips the rest of the rules in the .drl when statefulKnowledgeSession.fireAllRules() is used?

Comment: The term "skip" is misleading. `halt()` terminates, stops, discontinues,... execution and control passes to the statement following the fire...() call.

Comment: It means it won't execute the rest of the rules then it doesn't fulfil the purpose.

Comment: What is the purpose? - You have a way of terminating a single right hand side execution, and you have a way of terminating the execution of fire...().

Comment: Then you know the answer.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood what you are saying but I don't know the answer. It could be because of my restricted knowledge of drools.